# Smack throws NullPointerException in Roster's presence listener

Tags: xmpp, smack

I'm using Smack with android chatting applications and recently I have updated Smack to version to 4.3.0 and getting some error in fabric. It is a `NullPointerException` inside of Smack:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get (ConcurrentHashMap.java:772)
org.jivesoftware.smack.roster.Roster.getPresencesInternal (Roster.java:374)
org.jivesoftware.smack.roster.Roster.getOrCreatePresencesInternal (Roster.java:388)
org.jivesoftware.smack.roster.Roster.access$1100 (Roster.java:94)
org.jivesoftware.smack.roster.Roster$PresencePacketListener$1.run (Roster.java:1502)
org.jivesoftware.smack.AsyncButOrdered$Handler.run (AsyncButOrdered.java:121)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Can you please post your code as well for better understanding ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Its not about java null pointer exception. Its in smack library crash.

Comment: `Its not about java null pointer exception` Then your logcat is telling you lies...

Answer (score 1):

> "Use the source, Luke (and study the relevant open standard)" <sup>Obi-Wan Kenobi</sup>

Smack is open soure, so let us look at the source: One interesting part is

`org.jivesoftware.smack.roster.Roster.getPresencesInternal (Roster.java:374)`

which reads

```
Map<Resourcepart, Presence> entityPresences = presenceMap.get(entity);
```

<sup>Source: https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/4.3.0/smack-im/src/main/java/org/jivesoftware/smack/roster/Roster.java#L374</sup>

We also find that `presenceMap` is declared as follows

```
private final Map<BareJid, Map<Resourcepart, Presence>> presenceMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

<sup>Source: https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/4.3.0/smack-im/src/main/java/org/jivesoftware/smack/roster/Roster.java#L168</sup>

So it is a `ConcurrentHashMap`, which matches with the stacktrace. It is obvous that `entity` above is `null`, which is the cause of the `NullPointerException`.

Now we need to walk the call stack up (or down, depening on your point of view), to determine where `entity` origins from. Here the interesting part is

`org.jivesoftware.smack.roster.Roster$PresencePacketListener$1.run (Roster.java:1502)`

which reads

```
userPresences = getOrCreatePresencesInternal(key);
```

<sup>Source: https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/4.3.0/smack-im/src/main/java/org/jivesoftware/smack/roster/Roster.java#L1562</sup>

so `enitty` is `key` here. Which is declare and define just a few lines above

```
final BareJid key = from != null ? from.asBareJid() : null;
```

<sup>Source: https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/4.3.0/smack-im/src/main/java/org/jivesoftware/smack/roster/Roster.java#L1562</sup>

So in case `from` is `null,` key`will also be null. Which later causes the`NullPointerException`. Looking at the code, we find that this is caused by a presence XMPP stanza without a` from` attribute set.

The question is now if those stanzas are legal in XMPP. To determine that, we need to have a look at the specification. The relevant part is [RFC 6120 § 8.1.2.1 4.],[1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-8.1.2.1), which states

> When the server generates a stanza from the server for delivery
> to the client on behalf of the account of the connected client
> (e.g., in the context of data storage services provided by the
> server on behalf of the client), the stanza MUST either (a) not
> include a 'from' attribute or (b) include a 'from' attribute
> whose value is the account's bare JID (localpart@domainpart).

So a missing 'from' attribute is generally allowed and is equal to the "account's bare JID".

Now the question is: Are there any presence stanzas specified send from the server to the client which do not have a 'from' attribute? I could not find any while reading the related [RFC 6121](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6121). And I am not aware when this should ever happen (I possibly could be missing someting). But right now this appears to be a bug in the entity which creates those presence stanzas, which is the used XMPP server implementation.

(What XMPP server implementation do you use?).

Comment: Hi @Flow, thanks for you answer, But i got to know that main issue is coming from server, and its related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53005782/openfire-chatting-unexpected-behavior.